# Update records in subform powered by joined tables

Tags: ms-access

My access database contains the following tables: Person, Object, and Sub.

Sub is the relationship table between Person and Object. A Object can have at most 1 Person, a Person can have any number of Objects.

I've got a Person form showing the details of a Person and a datasheet subform, showing all assigned Objects of the Person - that is, the composite primary key (two fields) of Object and two additional columns from the Sub table.

So far everything works. I can insert, update and delete Sub assignments from within the Person form. But the subform should also show two columns from the Object table as well. If I simply set the subform datasource to a joined query, I can still insert records but not update existing ones:

> The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship.

I've tried using an outer join and subselects then, but I can't get it to work. I've changed the textfields of the Object columns to comboboxes in the design view so I could use a separate query, but I can only enter one bounded column - but I've got a composite primary key.

How can I display those two additional columns without breaking modifications?

Comment: Either your database design is seriously weird, or your description is somewhat lacking. If you have a 1:N relationship between `Person` and `Object`, you just need two tables: `Person` and `Object`, the latter having a foreign key into the `Person` table. Does `Sub` exist solely to connect `Person` and `Object`, or does it have additional data. If so, how are `Sub` and `Object` related?

Comment: Sub does have additional data. It exists to avoid NULL values, as a Object doesn't necessarily have to have a Person.

Comment: You could always use DLookup fields to display (but not alter) additional fields from other tables. The relation of `Sub` and `Object` still is unclear to me, and does seem a bit fishy. A table to _avoid NULL values_? srsly?